# keyval: pass unknown options to a command

Tags: key-value

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{my}{foo}[]{foo is enabled\par}
\define@key{my}{bar}[0]{bar is set to #1\par}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\somecommand}[2][none]{arg 1: #1, arg 2: #2}
\newcommand{\othercommand}[2][]{\setkeys{my}{#1} \somecommand{#2}}

\begin{document}

\othercommand[foo,bar=9]{baz}

\end{document}
```

This works fine as long as the only optional arguments passed to `\othercommand` are either `foo` or `bar`. Since these are optional arguments, they may be omitted as well. But what I would like to do now is the following: if there is another optional argument given, not known to the `\othercommand`, it shall be passed to the `\somecommand`. Example: if I write

`\othercommand[foo, bar=29, zap=12]{baz}`

I want the options `foo` and `bar` still be processed by the `\othercommand`. But the `zap=12` option is not known, so it shall be passed to `\somecommand` without modification, such that I can write

`\newcommand{\othercommand}[2][]{\setkeys{my}{#1} \somecommand[pass unknown options here]{#2}}`

For documentclasses, there is a command like "pass options to class" which passes unknown documentclass options to the underlying document class. I wonder whether such a mechanism can be used here as well.

Comment: Does `\somecommand` also accept `foo` and `bar` as options?

Comment: keyval has a command `\KV@errx` that you could redefine to handle unknown keys, but imho it would be better to use a newer keyval package like l3keys from expl3 which has built-in handlers for this case.

Comment: Werner, the `\somecommand` only accepts `zap` as optional argument, but neither `foo` nor `bar`. So these should not be passed to the `\somecommand`.

Comment: Ulrike, could you show a sample? I have absolutely no idea about this l3 topic. I have never used it before and the syntax seems even more complicated to me than the "old" syntax does. Perhaps I am not smart enough :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `l3keys` module of LaTeX3 has the function `\keys_set_known:nnN` which stores every unknown key in a token list.

You could use it in the following way:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% Inside of \ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff spaces are ignored and you have to
% use ~ to insert a space instead. Also _ and : can be part of macro names which
% is used to add some structure.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { my }
  {
     foo .code:n = { foo ~ is ~ enabled \par }
    ,foo .value_forbidden:n = { true }
    ,bar .code:n = { bar ~ is ~ set ~ to ~ #1\par }
    ,bar .default:n = { 0 }
  }
\tl_new:N \l__my_unknown_keys_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \othercommand { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set_known:nnN { my } {#1} \l__my_unknown_keys_tl
      \exp_args:NNo \somecommand [ \l__my_unknown_keys_tl ] {#2}
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { O{none} m }
  {
    arg ~ 1: ~ #1, ~ arg ~ 2: ~ #2\par
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to only use the optional argument of `\somecommand` if there were any unknown keys and else stick to its default, you could use:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% Inside of \ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff spaces are ignored and you have to
% use ~ to insert a space instead. Also _ and : can be part of macro names which
% is used to add some structure.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { my }
  {
     foo .code:n = { foo ~ is ~ enabled \par }
    ,foo .value_forbidden:n = { true }
    ,bar .code:n = { bar ~ is ~ set ~ to ~ #1\par }
    ,bar .default:n = { 0 }
  }
\tl_new:N \l__my_unknown_keys_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \othercommand { O{} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set_known:nnN { my } {#1} \l__my_unknown_keys_tl
      \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__my_unknown_keys_tl
        { \somecommand {#2} }
        { \exp_args:NNo \somecommand [ \l__my_unknown_keys_tl ] {#2} }
    \group_end:
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { O{none} m }
  {
    arg ~ 1: ~ #1, ~ arg ~ 2: ~ #2\par
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example how this could be done with `expkv`. Note that the unknown key isn't forwarded exactly like it was passed in (that information is lost when `expkv` has parsed the current key=val pair), but in a way in which *most* key=value packages would parse an equivalent value of pair (I say *most* because some of the wide spread packages have some issues regarding brace stripping, most notably it is possible that `pgfkeys` doesn't parse correctly something which is passed in as `key= {value}`).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\makeatletter
\ekvdefNoVal{my}{foo}{foo is enabled\par}
\ekvdef{my}{bar}{bar is set to #1\par}
\ekvdefNoVal{my}{bar}{bar is set to 0\par}
\newcommand\pluess@add@to@list[2]
  {%
    \ifx\@empty#1%
      \def#1{#2}%
    \else
      \edef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1,#2}}%
    \fi
  }
\ekvdefunknownNoVal{my}{\pluess@add@to@list\pluess@my@unknown@list{#1}}
\ekvdefunknown{my}{\pluess@add@to@list\pluess@my@unknown@list{#2= {#1}}}
\newcommand*\pluess@my@unknown@list{}
\ekvsetdef\my@set{my}

\newcommand\othercommand[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \let\pluess@my@unknown@list\@empty
      \my@set{#1}%
      \expandafter\somecommand\expandafter
        [\expandafter{\pluess@my@unknown@list}]%
        {#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\somecommand[2][none]{arg 1: #1, arg 2: #2\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to only use the optional argument of `\somecommand` if there were any unknown keys and else stick to its default, you could use:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\makeatletter
\ekvdefNoVal{my}{foo}{foo is enabled\par}
\ekvdef{my}{bar}{bar is set to #1\par}
\ekvdefNoVal{my}{bar}{bar is set to 0\par}
\newcommand\pluess@add@to@list[2]
  {%
    \ifx\@empty#1%
      \def#1{#2}%
    \else
      \edef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1,#2}}%
    \fi
  }
\ekvdefunknownNoVal{my}{\pluess@add@to@list\pluess@my@unknown@list{#1}}
\ekvdefunknown{my}{\pluess@add@to@list\pluess@my@unknown@list{#2= {#1}}}
\newcommand*\pluess@my@unknown@list{}
\ekvsetdef\my@set{my}

\newcommand\othercommand[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \let\pluess@my@unknown@list\@empty
      \my@set{#1}%
      \ifx\pluess@my@unknown@list\@empty
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {\somecommand}%
      {%
        \expandafter\somecommand\expandafter
          [\expandafter{\pluess@my@unknown@list}]%
      }%
      {#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\somecommand[2][none]{arg 1: #1, arg 2: #2\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.0 of `expkv-cs` (released on 2021-06-20) this is trivial, though the built in possibilities with `expkv-cs` are quite limited compared to other key=value implementations (like, e.g., `expkv` with `expkv-def` or `l3keys` or `pgfkeys`), since `expkv-cs` almost exclusively works with argument forwarding and can't store arbitrary data in any macro.

However for most simple use cases it is really straight forward to create key=value taking macros. And with the `...` primary key specification introduced in v1.0 forwarding unknown keys is as complicated as using `#1`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\newcommand*\somecommand{\ekvoptarg\somecommandOUT{}}
\newcommand\somecommandOUT[2]
  {arg 1: \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}, arg 2: #2\par\medskip}
\newcommand*\fooflag{} % make sure the name isn't yet taken
\ekvcFlagNew\fooflag   % define it as a flag
\newcommand*\othercommand
  {%
    % set the flag to be false
    \ekvcFlagSetFalse\fooflag
    \ekvoptarg\othercommandKEYS{}%
  }
\ekvcSplitAndForward\othercommandKEYS\othercommandOUT
  {%
     bar = -1 % will be #1 in \othercommandOUT
    ,...      % will be #2 in \othercommandOUT
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\othercommandKEYS
  {%
    % Set up keys to handle foo. It'll not use argument forwarding but instead
    % flags. Those are computationally expensive though, an argument forwarding
    % mechanism with a bit of manual parsing might be better here
     flag-bool foo = \fooflag
    ,flag-true foo = \fooflag
    ,default bar = 0
  }
\newcommand\othercommandOUT[2]
  {%
    \ekvcFlagIf\fooflag{foo is enabled\par}{}%
    bar is set to #1\par
    \somecommand[{#2}]% mandatory argument curried
  }

\begin{document}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

You'll notice that this example also didn't use LaTeX2e's standard mechanism for optional arguments but instead used `\ekvoptarg`. This has the advantage of being fully expandable (downside: the optional argument must be followed by a mandatory argument; and a mandatory argument `{[}` can't be distinguished from the beginning of the optional argument).

---

Another variant which doesn't use flags for `foo`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\somecommand{\ekvoptarg\somecommandOUT{}}
\newcommand\somecommandOUT[2]
  {arg 1: \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}, arg 2: #2\par\medskip}
\newcommand*\othercommand{\ekvoptarg\othercommandKEYS{}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\othercommandKEYS\othercommandOUT
  {%
     bar = -1 % will be #1 in \othercommandOUT
    ,...      % will be #2 in \othercommandOUT
    ,foo-internal=\@secondoftwo % will be #3
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\othercommandKEYS
  {%
     nmeta foo = foo-internal=\@firstoftwo
    ,meta  foo = foo-internal=\@firstoftwo
    ,default bar = 0
  }
\newcommand\othercommandOUT[3]
  {%
    #3{foo is enabled\par}{}%
    bar is set to #1\par
    \somecommand[{#2}]% mandatory argument curried
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\othercommand[foo, bar=9]{baz}
\othercommand{baz}
\othercommand[foo, bar, zip=12]{baz}
\end{document}
```

---

Output of both:

[image]